# How can I make HttpContext available to be used by my Unit Tests?

Tags: .net, asp.net, unit-testing, httpcontext, httpserverutility

I want to write a unit test which tests the function of a class called UploadedFile.

The problem I face is this class' static constructor uses HttpContext.Current property and because I am running my unit test from a class library I do not have an HttpContext at the testing time.

Look at my static constructor:

```
static UploadedFile()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        throw new Exception("web server not available");

    HttpServerUtility server = HttpContext.Current.Server;

    // SET UploadedFileMappingFile Names:
    _resourceFileNames = new StringDictionary();

    _resourceFileNames[_suppoertedFileStructures] = server.MapPath(SupportedUploadedFileStructures);
    _resourceFileNames[_supportedFileStructuresXSD] = server.MapPath(SupportedUploadedFileStructuresXSD);

    _resourceFileNames[UploadedFileEnum.UploadedFileFormatENUM.CSV.ToString()] = server.MapPath(UploadedFileColumnMap);        
}
```

What should I do in my testing environment so that `HttpContext.Current` won't be null and I can successfully set this:

```
 HttpServerUtility server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use `HttpContext.Current` directly in your function as it is close to impossible to unit test, as you've already found out. I would suggest you using [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) instead, which is passed either in the constructor of your class or as an argument to the method you are testing. This will allow the consumers of this class to pass a real [HttpContextWrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper.aspx) and in your unit test you can mock the methods you need.

For example here's how you could call the method:

```
var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
Foo.UploadedFile(wrapper);
```

And in your unit test (using [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)):

```
var contextMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
// TODO: Define expectations on the mocked object
Foo.UploadedFile(contextMock);
```

Or, if you prefer, use [Constructor Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I have not used Rhino.Mocks.dll so far unfortunately. It seems I have to get familiar with it first then I will try to implement your suggestion. Thanks!